# Error in opencv program: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: c, opencv

I try to compare two images in C language with OpenCV  .I tried this code :

```
cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff(src,dst,diff);
cv::Mat image;
cv::cvtColor(diff,image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
if (CountNonZero(image)==0)
printf("welcome you are autorised");
else 
printf("Sorry you are not welcome");

return 0;
}
```

This is the error i get when running the program :

```
 OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is 
neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same 
number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in 
arithm_op, file /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv- 
2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1287
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/opencv-ys8xiq/opencv- 
2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1287: error: (-209) The operation 
is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same 
number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in 
function arithm_op

Aborted (core dumped)
```

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: cv::absdiff  inputs should have the same size & channels.  make sure (src,dst) have the same size & channels.

Comment: Thnx I will try to solve it.